# Combinatorics on a graph with 1413 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

Let V be a set of size 1413.

(a) How many different graphs are there with vertex set V ?

I've determined the number of graphs with 1413 vertices is 2^1413C2

(b) How many different graphs with vertex set V and exactly m edges are there?

I've determined the number of graphs with 1413 vertices is 2^m

(c) Let suppose that {x, y} ≠ {x′, y′} are two element subsets of V . A graph G with vertex set V is picked uniformly at random. Are the events “{x, y} is an edge” and “{x′, y′}” is an edge independent?

I would say the number of subsets = (2^1413) - 1

Let A = {x, y}, and B = {x′, y′}, then if independent P(A n B) = P(A) x P(B)

P(A) = P(B) = 1/((2^1413)-1)

I don't know if this is right, and if it is where to go from here...

Answer (score 1):

Graphs on $V$ are determined by the edge set, which is a subset of the subset of all pairs of $V$ (assuming graphs have no directed edges and no loops, so a simple loopless graph; other types are possible).

So indeed we count the number of subsets of the set of pairs which has size $\binom{|V|}{2}$, so we get $$2^{\binom{|V|}{2}}$$ in full generality.

For exactly $m$ edges we want subsets from the pairs that have size exactly $m$, so there are

$$\binom{\binom{|V|}{2}}{m}$$ many of those.

As to $(c)$, common sense dictates that these events are indeed independent : we toss $\binom{|V|}{2}$ many coins (one per possible edge: in or out), and the coin for the one edge or the other are independent if we indeed chose the graphs aselectly.